# React app deployment failure on heroku "Failed to minify the code from this file"

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I created a react app using the create-react-app command and tried to deploy it on heroku using the directions on https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#quick-start

However while trying to push to heroku, I come up with the following Build Fail in which the build log reads:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
Failed to minify the code from this file: 
./node_modules/newsapi/index.js:17 
Read more here: 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sports-news-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sports-news-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-08-15T03_41_33_617Z-debug.log
!     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
!     Push failed
```

newsapi/index.js at line 17 reads

```
let API_KEY; // To be set by clients
```

Comment: What commands did you used before getting this error message?

Comment: git push heroku master

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the error could be without seeing `newsapi/index.js`. It is possible that the file includes syntax that is not supported or fails to be minified. One solution is to see if that line is an import, and create a local version of that dependency with the offending syntax removed or updated.

Comment: newsapi/index.js at line 17 reads: let API_KEY; // To be set by clients.

Comment: I tried changing 'let' to 'var' in my local nodemodule/newsapi/index.js but when I push to heroku master, it doesn't make a difference. I believe that it's because heroku doesn't check my local dependency, it checks the published newsapi module.